# Reversing a linked list iteratively with Pythonic variable swapping

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I was just practicing some Linked List questions when I came across something I couldn't explain. So I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

If I have a Linked List with nodes implemented as follows

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

I tried reversing the Linked List initially like so and it came up with an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'`

```py
prev = None
curr = head
while curr:
    prev, curr, curr.next = curr, curr.next, prev
```

And then I modified it to and it worked but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```py
prev = None
curr = head
while curr:
    curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
```

I'm aware that Python evaluates the RHS as a tuple and then assigns the values on the LHS from left to right but I can't seem to understand why both code snippets wouldn't be the same if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to visualize things the following way:

Your first code is equivalent to:

```
prev = None
curr = head
while curr:
    tmp = curr, curr.next, prev
    prev = tmp[0]
    curr = tmp[1]
    curr.next = tmp[2]
```

whereas your second code is equivalent to:

```
prev = None
curr = head
while curr:
    tmp = prev, curr, curr.next
    curr.next = tmp[0]
    prev = tmp[1]
    curr = tmp[2]
```

you see the difference is, that in one case you first change `curr` and then you assign to `curr.next`, whereas in the other case
you first change `curr.next` and then reassign `curr`.

python executes nothing in parallel.

It has to chose an order which is left to right for the variables to be assigned to.